# SpriteKit Scene referenced with SKReferenceNode does not load custom class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skreferencenode

I have a `GameScene.sks` a custom class `GameScene.swift` which is connected via the Custom Class Inspector (on the right in Xcode). This is working fine.

Now in the `GameScene.swift` where I want to reference another scene that I want to reuse in many scenes in the future (oversimplified code):

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
  // ...
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    //...

    guard let gameMenuPath = Bundle.main.path(
      forResource: "GameMenu", ofType: "sks") else { return }

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: gameMenuPath) as URL
    let gameMenu = SKReferenceNode(url: url)

    addChild(gameMenu)

    //...
```

where I am loading a reusable `GameMenu.sks`.

Everything works fine till here. Now the custom class issue for the `GameMenu.sks` (the scene to be reused). For the `GameMenu.sks` I also have a `GameMenu.swift` which is referenced in the custom class inspector as custom class. So exactly as for the `GameScene`. The problem is that it seems like the `GameMenu.swift` is not found/loaded. I get no error - so it looks like I misspelled the custom class - but I checkt it many times and also cleared the Xcode cache.

Any ideas how to set custom class for a scene (`.sks`) that is referenced in another scene?

I would think this is something that is done for reusable scene parts suche as the `GameMenu` in my case that is visible in every `GameScene`.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Just do `SKReferenceNode(fileNamed:”GameMenu”)`

Comment: Also, how do you know the swift class is different?

Comment: Yes, `SKReferenceNode(fileNamed:”GameMenu”)` works, but it does not help with the `custom class` (`GameMenu.swift`) which is still not loaded. I get the feeling that custom classes cannot be attached to scenes that are loaded via `SKReferenceNode`.

Comment: What do you mean custom classes cannot attach?  I know you are doing something wrong, I just can’t explain to you how you are wrong.  Tell me how you verify you do not have the right class

Comment: Hi. As I described in the question imagine two scenes both with a `.sks`AND a `swift` file. The `swift` file is connected via the `attributes inspector` `custom class` (right side). Both scenes are working as they should and I can override `func didMove` to do custom functions.

Now with exactly the same two scenes: As soon as I reference one scene via `SKReferenceNode` this references scene `custom class` is not working any more.

Comment: How do you know it is not referencing it, I need to know your diagnostic. Tell me exactly what is happening for you to say “Hmm, my custom class is not being used”

Comment: The code is not executed in the references swift file: 
`override func didMove(to view: SKView) { super.didMove(to: view); print("should be executed but is not") }
`

Comment: That will not get called.  That only gets called when an `SKView.presentScene` is called

Comment: You need to treat this like any other node being added to your scene

Comment: OK, thank you. This explains why the scene behaves "differently" after being references within other scenes. I will do the scene behaviour without (outside) the `custom class` for referenced scenes.

Comment: You just need to manually call the didview

Comment: Cannot do `didView` on a `SKReferenceNode`. In my case `gameMenu.didView...` if I understand you right.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to add GameMenu in GameScene via code? You can also simply use the inspector. In your GameScene.sks drop the 'Reference' (SKReferenceNode) object. Select it from the hierarchy and select GameMenu as in the 'reference' dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can do that and I also tried this. It still does not pull the `custom class` and does not improve the problem. Since I have many scenes I rather reference the scene (it happens automatically through inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

SKReferenceNodes behave as nodes, not as scenes, which may cause confusion since you are creating a scene file.

This means none of the functions that a view calls on a scene will be called.

If you need some of these functions to call, you need to do it manually.

Look at this example to get your didMoveToView to fire:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let gameMenu = SKReferenceNode(fileNamed:"GameMenu") as? SKScene // (or your custom class)

    addChild(gameMenu)
    gameMenu.didMove(to:view)
 }
```

Comment: I haven't played with reference nodes, I can't remember if it adds parent node or not

Comment: also, you do not even need SKReferenceNode, you can use your game glass.  ReferenceNodes are really pointless

Comment: `SKReferenceNodes behave as nodes` is really helpful to "rewire" my thinking. BTW `gameMenu.didMove(to:view)` is not possible, but the general gist helped me - thank you.

Comment: Skscenes also behave as nodes, so does your class, so does using just SKNode.  It is mostly use for code readability only

Comment: it also helps the Scenebuilder know it is a reference, but as far as you the developer is concerned, it has no significant purpose